# Hierarchy Custom Setting in validation rule

Tags: customsetting

I have a hierarchy custom setting with 2 custom checkbox fields & 3 profiles. I'm trying to use this profile based value in Validation rule. I have created the OWD on custom setting to be false & gave individual checkbox values at profile entires. However, the setup doesn't work as expected when i ran a test class with running user as sales (userrole.Name = Sales). The Validation rule fires irrespective of the BypassValidationRule__c values corresponding to the user's profile.

```
AND( 
OR( 
TEXT(StageName) = "Stage 3", 
TEXT(StageName) = "Stage 4"), 
($UserRole.Name = "Sales"),
($Setup.BypassRules__c.BypassValidationRule__c = false)
)
```

[image]

I know how to get specific values in apex but not sure about the validation or formula with respect to above. Any help on this would really be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hierarchical custom settings are based on Org Wide, Profile and User. Roles does not come in picture here. Also you have to create the custom settings in test class as well

Comment: Thanks for the response @PranayJaiswal, yes you can ignore the role statement that i mentioned above, what i meant was test class running user is a Sales Profile user, do i still need to add the custom settings in test class. Im little confused on this as when i tried this with List Type custom setting with just a single checkbox, it worked as expected. But when i tried it with hierarchy setting, i see this issue. Not sure why the contrast occurred.

Comment: You have to insert custom setting values for that profile even in test context. If am not wrong you might have created Custom metaData instead of list custom settings. Custom metaData is metaData so you don't create them in test context

Comment: Ok, will do that. Is this the right way or is there any better way to bypass validation, workflows or processbuilder. Pls recommend the best or widely used one

Comment: I havent used custom metadata, i only used the list type custom setting

Comment: Hierarchical custom settings are a good way to selectively bypass VR -if you put the condition in every VR, you can turn off all VRs using an org-wide value; or, disable for a specific profile, or disable for a specific integration user. For test methods, Pranay is right - you need to insert value(s) to have them apply

Comment: Thank you @cropredy. This validation is on opportunity level, looks like i need to add custom settings in all the test classes - methods where ever opp is inserted. Just thinking if this worth a change or i can manually disable VRs whenever i run test classes. I know the later is not the best way to do.

Comment: oh -- this is a bad path to go down; better to have test data factories that return valid records for insertion than to disable VRs just for testing. Otherwise, your test suite is masking real behavior and you could run into issues once you deploy